# Parts of speech in the question: "Which one?"

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, parts-of-speech

Is the word "one" a noun or a pronoun in the question "Which one?".
I suppose that the word "which" is an adjective. Am I right?

Comment: No, that's incorrect. "Which" is an interrogative determinative. And "one" can only be a common noun because pronouns do not take determiners. In your example "one" acts a pro-form, e.g. A: Here are the DVDs; which one would you like"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Which one?" is generally preceded by a statement which contains a list of items/things, and then the question is to pick one of them.

Since the word "one" here represents to a specific item/thing in that list of items/things, it is definitely a pronoun.

The word "which" is an interrogative adjective here as it is modifying a pronoun ("one"), and is appearing in an interrogative sentence.

[Source](http://www.k12reader.com/term/interrogative-adjectives/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is quite wrong. First, "which" is not an interrogative adjective but an interrogative **determinative** functioning  as a determiner; second: "one" is not a pronoun because pronouns don't take determiners and nor do they inflect for number ("ones"); it is actually a **common noun** acting as a pro-form. Note that all pro-forms are pronouns.

Comment: I have answered with my limited capacity of knowledge. Kindly add a new answer instead of commenting here. That'd be more beneficial for the OP. If I am wrong, vote me down. That's how the system works.

Comment: I'm aware of how the system works, but you should be aware that if you only have a "limited capacity of knowledge", it might be advisable not to submit answers that may be wrong or at least misleading.

Comment: Just downvote and move on. Let the community decide.

Answer (score 1):

"Which one"

"Which" is not an interrogative adjective but an interrogative determinative functioning as a determiner.

"One" is not a pronoun because pronouns don't take determiners and nor do they inflect for number ("which ones"); it is actually a common noun acting as a pro-form. Note that not all pro-forms are pronouns.

Comment: This is an answer and must be addressing the OP, not me!

Comment: @Cincout. It is addressed to the OP, not you.

Comment: Is it? The OP doesn't seem to be wrong on *two* counts. He has guessed answer to only one of his questions. Myself, on the other hand,...